# Create attributes via code

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I'm developing an extension, in which I need to create a tab in all products containing 9 new attributes. What would be the best way to do it?

My attributes are: 
Seller ID, Resale Price, Resale Price without ST, Available, Estq, Active and AvailableEstq

Comment: You can create product attributes from admin panel and then can assign all your 9 attributes to your attribute group. refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnBhX8byJKs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Setup script to craete products attribute programmatically. Like below you can add your attributes in setup script andas per the requirement, you can change the input type of attribute.

```
$this->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'seller_id', array(
    'group'           => 'General',
    'label'           => 'Seller ID',
    'input'           => 'text',
    'type'            => 'varchar',
    'required'        => 0,
    'visible_on_front'=> 1,
    'filterable'      => 0,
    'searchable'      => 0,
    'comparable'      => 0,
    'user_defined'    => 1,
    'is_configurable' => 0,
    'global'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'note'            => '',
));

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'available', array(
    'group'           => 'General',
    'label'           => 'Available',
    'input'           => 'text',
    'type'            => 'varchar',
    'required'        => 0,
    'visible_on_front'=> 1,
    'filterable'      => 0,
    'searchable'      => 0,
    'comparable'      => 0,
    'user_defined'    => 1,
    'is_configurable' => 0,
    'global'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'note'            => '',
));

$this->endSetup();
```

By default all these newly created attributes assigned into default attribute set.

You can add product attribute in other attribute set as well. Like Assign `seller_id` attribute to the '**Default**' attribute set under '**General**' group, just write like this:

```
$installer->addAttributeToSet('catalog_product', 'Default', 'General', 'seller_id')
```

There are many tutorials available on web that share step by step explanation.